# Is the BMJ a reliable source for biology studies?

Tags: human-biology

The BMJ published the Wakefield study, criticised it, and retracted it. They then argued that the Wakefield results they published were fradulent. Is BMJ reliable for biology studies or is it an anti vaccine conspiracy journal?

Comment: The Lancet published the study, the BMJ are the ones that exposed its fraudulence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: The infamous study by Wakefield et al., was published 1998 in Lancet, see [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9500320). Wakefield had indeed falsified his study, by selecting kids with certain preconditions, taking money from attorneys (and not disclosing it) and others. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Wakefield) is a nice overview over it.

To your question: The British Journal of Medicine (BMJ) is indeed a reliable and credible source for scientific articles, as is the Lancet. Journals can check the content they get for publication to some extent, but if they have authors who deliberately falsify studies, then they can do little. The thing which can be criticized in the Wakefield case is the time that it took to withdraw this publication.

Comment: But there would be obvious inconsistencies if the results were fake.

Comment: If these are obvious, journals will most likely not accept the article. See pubpeer...

Comment: BUT they accepted wakefield

Comment: @Bobb so what's your point? I could write a paper with completely falsified data, add some collaborators who generated their own and described it truthfully enough, write a convincing but incorrect conclusion, and get it published in a mid to top tier journal. If someone is smart enough, they can get around the current checks in the system unless an incredibly thorough review is done and the results are essentially independently generated again, which almost never happens before publication. There is, and always will be some level of trust in the system, otherwise nothing would get published.

Comment: Hmm. Sounds like peer review is almost useless.

Comment: @Bobb Exactly as MattDMo says. There are pther cases, like the one of Olivier Voinnet who recently had to retract 7(!) papers and correct at least 15 (I lost track here) and return prestigious prices. This guy was once a star, but has now fallen. See ][here](https://forbetterscience.wordpress.com/2016/04/07/voinnet-aftermath-ethical-bankruptcy-of-academic-elites/).

Comment: Peer review has it's drawbacks, and they are known. The problem is, there is no better system available. And still: Almost all papers are ok.

Comment: @Bobb tell me, are you a scientist? Do you actually understand what the peer review process *is*? Have you ever submitted a paper for publication to a halfway decent journal? If not, you very likely don't know what you're talking about. No one who actually knows what the process is and/or has been through it would say it's "almost useless." And if it *is* useless, what's your better alternative? I'm sure you've thought that through very carefully...

Comment: @Bobb if you're just here to troll, you will very quickly find yourself banned from the site, and potentially all Stack Exchange sites. If you want to engage in a thoughtful conversation about the pros and cons of the current system and how it can be fixed, fine. If you're just going to make asinine comments displaying your obvious ignorance about the subject, you may as well just leave now.

Comment: @Bobb peer review is good at identifying scientific quality but less so at detecting deliberate fraud. This is fairly well understood within the community (https://www.elsevier.com/reviewers-update/story/peer-review/as-peer-review-week-2016-begins,-our-infographic-highlights-what-researchers-really-think-about-the-current-process/) and is one motivation for the Reproducibility Initiative (see also http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/74761/who-is-supposed-to-repeat-experiments).

Comment: +1 for the important point, that the problem was how long the study took to be pulled and the fact that the Lancets own investigation was so poor another journal had to show its fraudulence.